# My search Folder function is not working?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am checking the Folder names in the Directory. It has 79 folders altogether in it but when I print them on the console I get only 49.
My code:

```
        StreamWriter sw;
        string dirPath = @"F:\Path\";
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
        int i = 1;
        sw = new StreamWriter(dirPath + "Pathlist.txt");
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dirPath))
        {
            string[] s = d.Split('\\');
            sw.Write(i + ". " + s[2] + Environment.NewLine);
            i++;
        }
```

But when I debug my code it goes through all folders and gets they names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`File.WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines.aspx) method to write collection of strings to a file.

`Directory.GetDirectories` with the `SearchOption.AllDirectories` will give you all the directories and sub directories of the given path

by using `Path.GetFileName` method you can get the last directory name of the path.

use `Path.Combine` when you join one or many strings as a path.

```
string path =Path.Combine(dirPath, "Pathlist.txt");

File.WriteAllLines(path,
             Directory.GetDirectories(dirPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                 .Select(d=>Path.GetFileName(d)));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string dirPath = @"F:\Path\";
if(Directory.Exists(dirPath))
{
   if(File.Exists(dirPath+"\\Pathlist.txt"))
    {
         /// Do your Code here 
         /// As Damith Said do this 
        File.WriteAllLines(path,Directory.GetDirectories(dirPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
             .Select(d=>Path.GetFileName(d)));

    }
}
```

Comment: Well the directory exist and File also exists. But it doesn't write all of the folder names only 49.

Comment: as damith said do that